# Dropdown popup not display while search on autocompletetextview inside recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have stuck with this issue more then 3 days. I have used one RecyclerView and on recyclerview's each item have on AutoCompleteTextView. When try to search on autocompletetextview drop down not display. Please do some help that how or where I need to update my code to use atutocomplettextview in every recyclerview items.

I have tried below are the cases:

1. To show popup manually `autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()`
2. notify adapter when user is typing in autocompletetextview
3. Every time reset the new adapter once use type on autocompletetextview
4. I have tried all the option's of `android:windowSoftInputMode=""` in AndroidMenifest
5. Checked more then 20+ questions on StackOver
6. I have tried to set ArrayAdapter from `onBindViewHolder()` method also

Below are the my code:

This is activity xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com..job..i.viewModel.job.JobViewModel" />
        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/screenBG"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvSupervisor"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:itemCount="1"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/job_filter_adapter" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is adapter class

```
public class JobFilterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    public final String tag = JobFilterAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private final Activity _activity;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<StaffInfo> _staffList;
    private final List<String> jobList;


    public JobFilterAdapter(Activity activity, List<StaffInfo> staffList,
                           List<String> list) {
        jobStaffAdapter = this;
        _activity = activity;
        inflater = _activity.getLayoutInflater();
        _staffList = staffList;
        jobList = list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new AdapterHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.row_job, parent, false),
                new JObWatcher());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        AdapterHolder adapterHolder = (AdapterHolder) holder;
        
        StaffInfo model = _staffList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        adapterHolder.binding.autoCompleteTxtJob.setText(model.getStaffNo(), false);
        adapterHolder.binding.txtStaffName.setText(model.getStaffName());
        
        adapterHolder.jobWatcher.updateState(position, adapterHolder);
        
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _staffList.size();
    }


    class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final RowJobBinding binding;
        JObWatcher jobWatcher;
        ArrayAdapter jobArrayAdapter;

        public AdapterHolder(@NonNull RowJobBinding _binding, JObWatcher _jobWatcher) {
            super(_binding.getRoot());
            binding = _binding;
            jobWatcher = _jobWatcher;

            jobArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(_activity, R.layout.row_job_item,jobList);
            binding.autoCompleteTxtJob.setThreshold(1);
        }

    }

    public class JObWatcher {
        int position;
        AdapterHolder holder;

        private void updateState(int pos, AdapterHolder viewHolder) {
            position = pos;
            holder = viewHolder;
            manageAutoText();
        }

        private void manageAutoText() {
            holder.binding.autoCompleteTxtJob.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, b) -> {
                if (b) {
                    holder.binding.autoCompleteTxtJob.setAdapter(holder.jobArrayAdapter);
                } else {
                    holder.binding.autoCompleteTxtJob.setAdapter(null);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is adapter's item xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/txtJobDetailRowLeft"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_job" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTxtJob"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_et_first"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/txtJobDetailRowLeft"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_staff_name" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtStaffName"
                    style="@style/txtJobDetailRowRight" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```